# JQuery.append() after ajax success is not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My mind is blowing up looking for the reason and the solution of my problem. I know I miss something but I have no idea where it is. My objective is having an ajax call after the drop down is changed, then append option in select multiple.

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#myselect').append("<option value='test1' selected>Test1</option>"); //this works

    $("#mydropdown").on('change', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "somepage.php",
            data: $("#someForm").serialize(),
            success: function(msg)
            {   
                alert("Hello World"); //this is triggered
                //below line of code does not work
                $('#myselect').append("<option value='test3' selected>Tes3</option>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: The request is probably returning an error. Try adding `error: function(xhr, status, error){console.log(error)}` to your request to check.

Comment: thanks but I did,no error returned.

Comment: Any console error? Is the ajax request even made?

Comment: no error at all in the console, thats correct, the ajax request is successful

Answer (score 0):

So I have got a work around to my problem. I put a div with a specific ID called theDiv around the select and initialize it as usual. Then in my AJAX request I put

```
$( "#theDiv" ).empty(); //empty the diev so that select will be removed
//append select
$("#theDiv").append('<select multiple="multiple" id="myselect" name="myselect[]"><option>Some option</option></select>');
InitalizeMultiSelect(); //re-initialize the multiSelect
```

Right now it is working OK for me. Might not be efficient but seems I did not found any way to de-initialize the multiSelect, so I guess this is the best solution for me.

Thank you for all your time and helps.

Answer (score -1):

the code

```
$('#myselect').append("<option value='test3' selected>Tes3</option>");
```

seems ok to me. But for instance check the two suggestion I am giving you

1) First try this

change `"<option value='test3' selected>Tes3</option>";`

to `'<option value="test3" selected>Tes3</option>'`

2) Also try to use `selected='selected'`

may be that can also cause problem

I misunderstood that myselect and mydropdown are same dropdowns..

Sorry, anyways your code is allright.

```
do one thing, try to remove the class of the #myselect(if any class is there) to see if your code works
```

Comment: thank you,trying now..update: second solution didn't work for me. I cannot do first solution as if I put this, this will not refer to my select id.

Comment: myselect is actually a <select multiple>. and I am using jQuery multiselect plugin from loudev.com. not sure if that is the problem but the first append worked.

Comment: Who is the self-proclaimed knowledgeable person who down-voted me? I would like to know why I was down-voted..

Comment: there is no class for #myselect

Comment: i also have once faced such problem, the append is working during the documet ready function. But once it gets attached on the html, then its hard to append the variables. I guess it something like that. Post me the link where i can see the selct you have taken from

Comment: $('#your-select').multiSelect('addOption', { value: 'test', text: 'test', index: 0, nested: 'optgroup_label' });

Comment: sorry what is that for? I found that the append works if I put the statement before $('#agentListGroupSelect').multiSelect({}); If I put after the initialization, it did not work. but even I put that in the last section, still it fails to append after the ajax requests.

Comment: thats what i wanted to tell you. The jquery wont let append after initialisation

Comment: How do I tackle this? any idea?

Comment: after ajax calling, remove() existing #myselect, then create a new one with same id and previous options and the new option, and again reinitialise it..

Comment: I failed to directly remove it once it has been initialized. If it is not  initialized yet, only then I can .remove() it.